# Using Scorer Object for Classifier Score Method

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have written my custom scorer object which is necessary for my problem and which I've called "p_value_scoring_object".

For the function sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score one of the parameters is "scoring", which allows to use this scorer object.

However, this option is not available for the score method of a classifier. Is sklearn just lacking that feature, or is there a way around it?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()
cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10,scoring=p_value_scoring_object)
```

This works. However, this doesn't:

```
clf.fit(iris.data,iris.target)
clf.score(iris.data,iris.target,scoring=p_value_scoring_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

sklearn just lacking that feature. Score is internally binded to different metrics for different types of estimators. For example classifiers are binded to classification accuracy score metric, for regressors it's binded to `r2_score`.

You can look at these binds in `sklearn.base`, every mixin (For example `ClassifierMixin`) provides this `score` method.

Istead of this you can just run:

```
p_value_scoring_object(p_value_scoring_object, iris.data, iris.target)
```